# Using in general at the end of a sentence

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

Consider this sentence:

> In this experiment, we just want to corroborate our previous results.

If we want to emphasize that we want to corroborate the results as a whole (e.g., if one or two instances are rejected among 1000 instances, it is still corroborated), can we change it to this:

> In this experiment, we just want to corroborate our previous results in general.

If not, what else can be used?

Comment: It's fine. You can also say, for your information: We just want to corroborate generally our previous results.

Answer (score 1):

"corroborate" refers to something particular, so I don't think "corroborate...in general" is a good combination. You are qualifying what you mean by "corroborate".

> The purpose of this experiment is to corroborate the results of the previous experiment with results that are *substantially the same*.

"substantially the same" indicates that minor differences will be overlooked as insignificant.